# Does react native enable live update without updating app?

Tags: react-native

I saw somewhere that you can update your code live in production with react-native (I can't remember where I saw it)

However, the javascript is bundled and packaged with the app, I don't think you can update javascript code without a new release.

Does react-native enable you to live update your js code in production or not?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push

Comment: React Native itself, AFAIK no. Google `react native live code update`

Comment: I feel @bhavesh-goyal answer is more generic since Code push can be used with generic ReactNative apps and you're not limited to Expo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ya you can manage it with expo or you can use third party continuous deployment tools like code-push from Microsoft.

https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push

- you can easily manage Staging and Production and environment.
- you can roll out to some percentage.
- can revert back.
- all the js code can be updated but no native code.Otherwise you may face crashing issues.